# JavaMail contact us swing form programming

Tags: java, swing, jakarta-mail

I want to program a "**Contact Us**" form in my desktop application (*Swing* in *Netbeans*), just like what we find in some websites.

The problem that I faced is the `smtp` server name. Actually, I want that the user could send me a message without giving his address mail and without requiring that he connects to his account either.

**Here a screen shot**:

[image]

And this is my **Submit button** action:

> ```
>     @Override
>     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
>         boolean isSent = true;
>         try {
>             //Properties properties = new Properties();
>             Properties properties = System.getProperties();
>            // properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.submitter", contactUs.getMailField().getText());
>             //properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
>             properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "localhost");
>             //properties.put("mail.smtp.user", txtfrom.getText());
>             //properties.put("mail.smtp.port", txtPort.getText());
>             //properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", txtPort.getText());
>             properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
>             properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
>             properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
>
>             //Authenticator mailAuthenticator = new MailAuthenticator();
>             Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
>             Message message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
>
>             InternetAddress fromAddress = new InternetAddress(contactUs.getMailField().getText());
>             InternetAddress toAddress = new InternetAddress("mancha@gmail.com");
>
>             message.setFrom(fromAddress);
>             message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);
>             message.setSubject(contactUs.getSubjectField().getText());
>             message.setText(contactUs.getMsgField().getText());
>             Transport.send(message);
>         } catch (Exception ex) {
>             contactUs.getErrorMsg().setText("ERROR:" + ex.getMessage());
>             isSent = false;
>         }
>         if (isSent == true) {
>             contactUs.getSubmitBtn().setEnabled(false);
>             contactUs.getErrorMsg().setText("Your e-mail has been sent.");
>         }
>     }
> ```

Of course I google and I found [that simple example](http://www.javatpoint.com/example-of-sending-email-using-java-mail-api) which causes always problem of connection to smtp server.

Comment: you need an smtp server of your own

Comment: Do you want to say that I configure a default smtp server (hiddern to end user)?

Comment: Your problem is not netbeans related, not Swing related, ... Also: why don't you show code of your own?

Comment: I put Swing to say that it deals with Desktop not web, and I put some code

Comment: I guess you dont have SMTP server on localhost ... 
Btw for gmail recepients, you can use free Google SMTP - look at there https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en 
- aspmx.l.google.com , port 25, no auth

Or recheck ports - netstat (-a -b) in cmd on win and netstat --listen on unix should works

Comment: Please consider the security implications of what you're doing.  You either need to run an open SMTP server with no authentication, or you need to embed the authentication information in your application, which can be extracted and misused.  It would probably be better to collect the information for the message and HTTP POST it to a web server you own, where you can do more checking on the validity of the requesting before sending it as email.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure that your smtp server listens on port 25.
you can check it via telnet.

```
telnet localhost 25
```

if you do not have any, install a smtp service to your system.
if you have, check your smtp services security settings to connect it

Answer (score 1):

Firstly check that your mail server is up and running by running

```
telnet localhost 25
```

Secondly you don't want to set the fromAddress as the users 'prescribed' email as that would require the account exists on your local mail server (As often people contacting you wouldn't already be on your system). Instead, temporarily hard code the fromAddress to an email address you know exists on your mail server and just append the users email address to the email.

An example of what you might want to do

```
final String FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS = yourexistingemail@mailserver.com;
InternetAddress fromAddress = new InternetAddress(FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS);

message.setText(contactUs.getMsgField().getText(), "\nFrom: " + contactUs.getMailField().getText());
```